# How do I use TensorFlow backend in keras without changing keras.json?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, ubuntu-16.04

Well, I am working on a GPU server. All other users are using `keras` with `Theano backend`.

I have installed `TensorFlow` using `virtualenv` and later I installed keras using usual `pip` command. When I try to run `keras` in this virtual environment, it is using `Theano` backend because of the `/home/user/.keras/keras.json` file. I know I can use `TensorFlow` by making changes in the json file but for some reason other users are not allowing this.

I would like to know if there is a way to use `keras` with `TensorFlow` installed in my virtual environment other than the globally installed `"Theano"`.

NOTE: The other users still should be able to use `Theano`

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using @GPhilo documentation reference;

I successfully used `TensorFlow` backend by adding following lines at the starting of my code:

```
import os
os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = 'tensorflow'
# rest of the code
```

Make sure you have activated your virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

From [Keras' documentation](https://keras.io/backend/):

> You can also define the environment variable `KERAS_BACKEND` and this
>   will override what is defined in your config file :
>
> `KERAS_BACKEND=tensorflow python -c "from keras import backend"
>   Using TensorFlow backend.`

Comment: wouldn't it change the backend for other users too?

Comment: No, you're setting an environment variable for your terminal, that won't affect anyone else and will be lost once you close the terminal.

Comment: If I do the same thing in the terminal it doesn't actually work. I found a workout with your suggestion though. Thanks!